# I can not sort the data alphabetically with neDB database

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, electron, nedb

it turns out that I have a problem with a database that I am using in electron with the [neDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) module. The problem I have is that it does not sort the values alphabetically if the field starts with a capital letter.

When I try to sort them in alphabetical order they come out completely disorganized. I have saved all the names in the database without uppercase and it orders them perfectly, it is a problem with the beginning of name with uppercase letter.

I tried to search the network if there was someone with the same problem and it seems that I have not found anyone. Maybe I'm doing something wrong

```
var db= new Datastore({filename: path.normalize(
        app.getPath('userData'))+'/base/people.db',
        autoload:true});

db.find({}).sort({'nom' : 1 }).skip(0).limit(15).exec(function (err, docs) {

        docs.forEach(function(doc, i, arr){



    var divNombre = document.createElement('div');

        divNombre.className='nombre';

        divFicha.appendChild(divNombre); 

    var textoNombre = document.createTextNode(doc.nom);

        divNombre.appendChild(textoNombre);


        });//docs.forEach(function(doc, i, arr)



    });
```

Small example of the database:

```
{"nom":"tpaggtff","iu":"5r55rr5rf","des":"fffffffffffff"_id":"2899ts0q","ba":"no"}
{"nom":"astohgff","idF":"5t554545","des":"frfrfrcrfrrrf","_id":"3omnamvi","ba":"no"}
{"nom":"Bettgnhitoz","idF":"dededed","des":"ddffff55f","_id":"au0oxhxy","ba":"no"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of executing your data is :

```
[ { nom: 'Bettgnhitoz',
    idF: 'dededed',
    des: 'ddffff55f',
    ba: 'no',
    _id: 'cDeLArtZYkVCHI7e' },
  { nom: 'astohgff',
    idF: '5t554545',
    des: 'frfrfrcrfrrrf',
    ba: 'no',
    _id: 'oC4CIUmxJ2kqHcMC' },
  { nom: 'tpaggtff',
    iu: '5r55rr5rf',
    des: 'fffffffffffff',
    ba: 'no',
    _id: 'CLucpeOhxsnSUua6' } ]
```

Which is accurate as the uppercase letters will be sorted before the smaller case letters, this is due to the order of the characters in the ASCII character set, check [this](https://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html).